# How to filter the last 7 days based on the previous query? -BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Hi I just want to ask how to resolve this problem.

Example in the query indicated below.

In the next query I will prepare, I want to filter the last 7 days of the delivery date. Do not use current_date because the maximum date is very late.
Assuming the current date is 7/12/2022 but the query shows a maximum date of 7/07/2022. How can   I filter the date from 7/1/2022 to 7/07/2022?

```sql
, Datas1 as 
(select distinct (delivery_due_date) as delivery_date 
, Specialist  
, Id_number
, Staff_Total as Total_Items 
from joining
where Delivery_Due_Date is not null 
)
```

Actually I used `max` function in `where` but I get an error. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Created Examples of such data in first block.
Performed the select on that data in second block.
Extracted Maximum Delivery data in 3rd Block.
Restricted last block for 7 days of data collected from 3rd block.

```
WITH joining AS(
SELECT '2022-07-01' AS delivery_due_date, 'ABC' as Specialist,222 as Id_number, 21 as Staff_Total union all
SELECT '2022-07-07' AS delivery_due_date, 'ABC2' as Specialist,223 as Id_number, 01 as Staff_Total union all
SELECT '2022-07-15' AS delivery_due_date, 'ABC4' as Specialist,212 as Id_number, 25 as Staff_Total union all
SELECT '2022-07-20' AS delivery_due_date, 'AB5C' as Specialist,224 as Id_number, 15 as Staff_Total union all
SELECT '2022-07-05' AS delivery_due_date, 'ABC7' as Specialist,226 as Id_number, 87 as Staff_Total ),


Datas1 as (select distinct (delivery_due_date) as delivery_date , Specialist
, Id_number , Staff_Total as Total_Items from joining where Delivery_Due_Date is not null ),

Datas2 as ( 
select max(delivery_date) as  ddd from Datas1)

select Datas1.* from Datas1,Datas2 where date(delivery_date) between date_sub(date(Datas2.ddd), interval 7 day) and date(Datas2.ddd)
```